# how to force signout another user in Identityserver 4?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, identityserver4

I authenticate my site user by IdentityServer4. In some cases, I need to logout some users forcibly as admin. is there any practical and standard method to signout another user in SigninManager class? or I need to perform some extra step manually?

According to @Rav's guidance, I am trying to call the revocation endpoint but how can I get access/refresh token of a user by its user name?

Comment: You'll have to expose a method which does that, based on a specific role.

Comment: can you provide more details?

Comment: you can revoke tokens, look at the following http://docs.identityserver.io/en/dev/endpoints/revocation.html

Comment: I try to call revoke endpoint but how can I access to user issued tokens by username or userId @Rav

Comment: I remove the user persisted grant but the user's session is still alive on IdentityServer (not clients) ...